# Strength reduction techniques with Bison

Tags: optimization, bison, bit-shift

I have a Bison parser generator and I'm looking for ways to optimize it. Would techniques such as bit shifting for multiplication and division, or creating checks for x*2 and changing it to x+x make it faster? Or is bison already optimized for this sort of thing.

Comment: Since bison does not have any multiplication or division anywhere in its language, its not clear what you are asking.  Of course, the C code in the actions can do those things, but that is just C code, and your C compiler will optimize it -- bison doesn't touch it.

Comment: | exp '*' exp 
        { if($3 ==2) $$ = $1 + $1; 
        $$ = $1 * $3; }

I meant defining it in the grammar like this.

Comment: Well, on most machines, a test+conditional branch is much more expensive than a multiply, so this is unlikely to ever help irrespective of bison.  But in general, bison doesn't touch/modify anything in `{}` -- it just passes it on to the C compiler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do it yourself. You are the one declaring what is the semantic of the operators, bison had no idea what it could be. What if you choose to implement `+` as `printf("error")` and `*` as `exp1.erase(exp2)`? Is `x+x` equals `2*x` in your language? Probably not.

Will optimization make it faster? It depends on your target language. You can measure, estimate and compare the cost of the two methods, and decide if that optimization is needed.